# The class you are trying to register is not available [TYPO3 8.7.26]

Tags: composer-php, typo3, content-management-system, typo3-8.x

I'm installing self created extensions in TYPO3. My composer.json file ar location /var/www/html/typo3 looks like:

```
{
        "repositories": [{
                        "type": "composer",
                        "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
                },
                {
                        "type": "package",
                        "package": {
                                "name": "Bm/ah-content-api",
                                "version": "0.0.1",
                                "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
                                "source": {
                                        "url": "https://user@bitbucket.org/company/ah_config_typo3.git",
                                        "type": "git",
                                        "reference": "master"
                                },
                                "autoload": {
                                        "psr-4": {
                                                "bm\\ah-content-api\\": "typo3conf/ext/ah-contentapi/Classes"
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },

                {
                        "type": "package",
                        "package": {
                                "name": "Bm/ah-contentelements",
                                "version": "0.0.1",
                                "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
                                "source": {
                                        "url": "https://user@bitbucket.org/company/ah_contentelements_typo3.git",
                                        "type": "git",
                                        "reference": "master"
                                },
                                "autoload": {
                                        "psr-4": {
                                                "bm\\ah-contentelements\\": "typo3conf/ext/ah-contentelements/Classes",
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        ],
"name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
        "description": "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
        "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
        "require": {
                "helhum/typo3-console": "^4.9.3 || ^5.2",
                "typo3/cms-about": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-belog": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-beuser": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-context-help": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-documentation": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-felogin": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-form": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-func": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-impexp": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-info": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-info-pagetsconfig": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-setup": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-wizard-crpages": "^8.7.10",
                "typo3/cms-wizard-sortpages": "^8.7.10",
                "dmitryd/typo3-realurl": "2.*",
                "GridElementsTeam/Gridelements": "8.2.*",
                "clickstorm/cs_seo": "3.*",
                "Bm/ah-content-api": "0.0.1",
                "Bm/ah-contentelements": "0.0.1"
        },
        "scripts": {
                "typo3-cms-scripts": [
                        "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure",
                        "typo3cms install:generatepackagestates"
                ],
                "post-autoload-dump": [
                        "@typo3-cms-scripts"
                ]
        },
        "extra": {
                "typo3/cms": {
                        "web-dir": "public"
                },
                "helhum/typo3-console": {
                        "comment": "This option is not needed ay more for helhum/typo3-console 5.x",
                        "install-extension-dummy": false
                }
        }
}
```

The data for the extensions are stored in the git repos. With each a composer.json file in the root:

```
{
  "name": "Bm/ah-contentelements",
  "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
  "description": "descr,
  "homepage": "http://www.company.de/",
  "suggest": {
  },
  "require": {
    "typo3/cms-core": ">=8.0.0,<9.0"
  },
  "author": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "email": "sdsd@company.de"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Bm\\AhContentelements\\": "Classes/"
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
 {
    "name": "bm/ah-content-api",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "description": "Content API Extension",
    "homepage": "http://www.company.de/",
    "license": [
        "GPL-2.0+"
    ],
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": ">=7.5.0,<9.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Bm\\AhContentapi\\": "Classes/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "ah_contentapi": "self.version",
        "typo3-ter/ah_contentapi" : "self.version"
    }
}
```

I ran following commands:
`sudo composer update`
`sudo composer dump-autoload`

Still there are classes not available in TYPO3.
Error message when I try to run:

```
#1411840171: The class "Bm\AhContentelements\Rendering\VideoTagRenderer" you are trying to register is not available
```

I'm using **TYPO3 8.7.26**

VideoTagRenderer:

```
<?php
namespace Bm\AhContentelements\Rendering;


/*
 * This file is part of the TYPO3 CMS project.
 *
 * It is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the GNU General Public License, either version 2
 * of the License, or any later version.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE.txt file that was distributed with this source code.
 *
 * The TYPO3 project - inspiring people to share!
 */

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference;

/**
 * Class VideoTagRenderer
 */
class VideoTagRenderer extends \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Rendering\VideoTagRenderer
{
    /**
     * Mime types that can be used in the HTML Video tag
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $possibleMimeTypes = ['video/mp4', 'video/webm', 'video/quicktime', 'video/ogg', 'application/ogg'];

    /**
     * Returns the priority of the renderer
     * This way it is possible to define/overrule a renderer
     * for a specific file type/context.
     * For example create a video renderer for a certain storage/driver type.
     * Should be between 1 and 100, 100 is more important than 1
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPriority()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    /**
     * Check if given File(Reference) can be rendered
     *
     * @param FileInterface $file File or FileReference to render
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canRender(FileInterface $file)
    {
        return in_array($file->getMimeType(), $this->possibleMimeTypes, true);
    }

    /**
     * Render for given File(Reference) HTML output
     *
     * @param FileInterface $file
     * @param int|string $width TYPO3 known format; examples: 220, 200m or 200c
     * @param int|string $height TYPO3 known format; examples: 220, 200m or 200c
     * @param array $options controls = TRUE/FALSE (default TRUE), autoplay = TRUE/FALSE (default FALSE), loop = TRUE/FALSE (default FALSE)
     * @param bool $usedPathsRelativeToCurrentScript See $file->getPublicUrl()
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(FileInterface $file, $width, $height, array $options = [], $usedPathsRelativeToCurrentScript = false)
    {

        // If autoplay isn't set manually check if $file is a FileReference take autoplay from there
        if (!isset($options['autoplay']) && $file instanceof FileReference) {
            $autoplay = $file->getProperty('autoplay');
            if ($autoplay !== null) {
                $options['autoplay'] = $autoplay;
            }
        }

        $attributes = [];
        if ((int)$width > 0) {
            $attributes[] = 'width="' . (int)$width . '"';
        }
        if ((int)$height > 0) {
            $attributes[] = 'height="' . (int)$height . '"';
        }
        if (!isset($options['controls']) || !empty($options['controls'])) {
            $attributes[] = 'controls';
        }
        if (!empty($options['autoplay'])) {
            $attributes[] = 'autoplay';
        }
        if (!empty($options['muted'])) {
            $attributes[] = 'muted';
        }
        if (!empty($options['loop'])) {
            $attributes[] = 'loop';
        }
        foreach (['class', 'dir', 'id', 'lang', 'style', 'title', 'accesskey', 'tabindex', 'onclick'] as $key) {
            if (!empty($options[$key])) {
                $attributes[] = $key . '="' . htmlspecialchars($options[$key]) . '"';
            }
        }

        $extension = $file->getExtension();
        if ('ogv' == $extension) {
            $extension = 'ogg';
        }

        $useMimetype = 'video/'.$extension;


        return sprintf(
            '<video%s><source src="%s" type="%s"></video>',
            empty($attributes) ? '' : ' ' . implode(' ', $attributes),
            htmlspecialchars($file->getPublicUrl($usedPathsRelativeToCurrentScript)),
            $useMimetype
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a small snippet of the `Bm\AhContentelements\Rendering\VideoTagRenderer`-class? So we can see you are using the right namespace

Comment: @unherz i added it to the original question

Comment: Why you're using `package` type for `repositiories` instead of `vcs`?

Comment: @rob006 what do you mean?

Comment: You're using [`package`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) type for your `repositories` section which have several limitations and usually you should avoid it. If you have regular repository with `composer.json` inside, it is better to use `vcs` type.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the linked article: **The problem is that the composer.json in you packages are ignored.**

Instead you have to set the correct psr-4 in your main composer.json file. I fixed the provided snippet to match it:

```
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Bm\\AhContentapi\\": "typo3conf/ext/ah-contentapi/Classes"
      }
    }

    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Bm\\AhContentelements\\": "typo3conf/ext/ah-contentelements/Classes"
      }
    }
```

http://blog.pepa.info/php-html-css/composer/composer-not-autoloading-your-package/

**Sidenote**: Remove the extra > helhum/typo3-console part || It's not needed anymore

**Edit 1:**
As long as the extensions are already part of your vcs code (checked in) you can simply avoid the repository part and simply add the following to your main composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Bm\\AhContentelements\\": "typo3conf/ext/ah-contentelements/Classes",
    "Bm\\AhContentapi\\": "typo3conf/ext/ah-contentapi/Classes"
  }
}
```

If the extensions are **NOT** part of your vcs/git repo you can simply use a convention from version 9 and extract your own extensions in a folder named Packages/ your TYPO3 root directory. Then you add the following "repository" entry instead of your current package entries:

```
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "Packages/*",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
```

After the next composer run you should see your extensions linked now.
Remember three things:

1. Symlink behavior based on a windows-filesystem **CAN** create incorrect symlinks during compsoer symlinking. Recreate them correctly afterwards.
2. Recheck the paths and be aware of any problems due to incorrect paths
3. The differences of `composer install` and `composer update`

Comment: I added an additional solution attempt

Comment: does the position of the autoload confs matters?

Comment: ps: i'm using v 8.7.26, not 9 :)